# How to counts the function of Mathematica have been split to some what aspects?

Tags: built-in-symbols, entity

According to following example,we can know the `Mathematica` classify every function in different aspect.

```
 EntityValue[
 Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Image"], "FunctionalityAreas"]
```

> Out[52]= {"ImageFunctions"}

```
EntityValue[
 Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Plot"], "FunctionalityAreas"]
```

> Out[53]= {"BasicFunctions", "PlottingFunctions"}

```
EntityValue[
 Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
  "BilateralFilter"], "FunctionalityAreas"]
```

> Out[54]= {"ImageFilterFunctions"}

But the question is how many types be classified in `Mathematica`.And what are these types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version `11.0.1`,the function be splited $175$ kinds

```
EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol","FunctionalityAreas",DeleteDuplicates@*Flatten]
```

> {CodeInterruptionSymbols,ChannelSymbols,MessagesAndPrintingSymbols,RestructuringSymbols,AsynchronousTaskSymbols,AudioSymbols,DirectorySymbols,StreamSymbols,BinaryDataSymbols,CloudSymbols,NotebookSymbols,FrontEndSymbols,MachineSymbols,CompileSymbols,ParallelSymbols,SymbolContextSymbols,HyperlinkSymbols,LinkSymbols,DateSymbols,LocalObjectSymbols,DynamicSymbols,ServiceSymbols,EntitySymbols,FileSystemSymbols,FontSymbols,GeodesySymbols,EnvironmentSymbols,ImageSymbols,DeviceSymbols,InterpreterSymbols,LibraryLinkSymbols,NumericsPrecisionSymbols,MathFunctions,RootSymbols,BasicSymbols,PackageSymbols,PlottingSymbols,RegionSymbols,ScheduledTaskSymbols,SoundSymbols,TemplateSymbols,TimeMemorySymbols,QuantitySymbols,GraphicsPrimitiveSymbols,StatisticalProcessSymbols,NamedGroupSymbols,AlignmentSymbols,ComplexSymbols,StatisticsSymbols,GraphicsSymbols,OptionSymbols,FormSymbols,ListSymbols,ControlObjectSymbols,CodeEvaluationSymbols,GraphBooleanPropertySymbols,SymbolAssignmentSymbols,GraphTheorySymbols,TimeSeriesSymbols,BoxSymbols,BoxOptions,PacletSymbols,ControlSystemSymbols,GeometricTransformSymbols,SpecialSymbols,AlgebraicSymbols,BooleanSymbols,CellSymbols,GrammarSymbols,StringSymbols,CDFSymbols,PatternSymbols,AstronomySymbols,MachineLearningSymbols,StatisticalTestSymbols,OperatorSymbols,GaugeSymbols,ControlObjectOptions,AnnotationSymbols,FinanceSymbols,LinearAlgebraSymbols,TensorSymbols,SetSymbols,VectorCalculusSymbols,StatisticalDistributionSymbols,MinMaxSymbols,ArraySymbols,MatrixSymbols,AskSymbols,AssociationSymbols,WolframAlphaSymbols,PolynomialSymbols,FrontEndOptions,AutocompleteSymbols,SignalProcessingSymbols,ChartSymbols,LegendSymbols,GraphDistributionSymbols,MathFunctionWindows,StyleSymbols,NetSymbols,WaveletSymbols,PacketSymbols,ExpressionTestingSymbols,ImageFilterSymbols,HistogramSymbols,ClusteringSymbols,BitSymbols,ColorSymbols,CodeActionSymbols,ModuleSymbols,TextStringSymbols,CodeFlowSymbols,NamedGraphSymbols,ButtonSymbols,ExpressionSizeSymbols,CalculusSymbols,FractalSymbols,RecurrenceSymbols,NumericConstantSymbols,GroupTheorySymbols,NumberTheorySymbols,DialogSymbols,SliderSymbols,ExtractionSymbols,InfinitySymbols,FunctionSymbols,SeriesSymbols,FittingSymbols,LogicSymbols,SymbolInformationSymbols,SearchSymbols,ContinuedFractionSymbols,ControllerSymbols,DatabinSymbols,PaletteSymbols,PermutationSymbols,SolvingSymbols,AngleSymbols,DatasetSymbols,GeoGraphicsPrimitiveSymbols,CryptographySymbols,MenuSymbols,DiscreteCalculusSymbols,NumericSymbols,IntegerSymbols,FormattingSymbols,RuleSymbols,ComparisonOperatorSymbols,ArrowOperatorSymbols,VectorTeeOperatorSymbols,SymbolValueSymbols,GeoGraphicsSymbols,DebugSymbols,DomainSymbols,QuantityVariableSymbols,NumberFieldSymbols,GlobalOptions,ViewerSymbols,ContinuousFourierSymbols,DiscreteFourierSymbols,FrontEndExecutionSymbols,InterpolationSymbols,StructuralSymbols,PageSymbols,RawExpressionSymbols,IntervalSymbols,ExternalProcessSymbols,RealSymbols,UndocumentedSymbols,NumberSymbols,Symbols,ResourceSymbols,TestSymbols,TravelSymbols}

Answer (score 7):

In 10.4 there are 173 functionality areas.

```
funcAreas = 
  Sort@DeleteDuplicates@*Flatten@
    WolframLanguageData[WolframLanguageData[], "FunctionalityAreas"];

Length@funcAreas
(* 173 *)
```

A quick browser with `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[
 Multicolumn[
  WolframLanguageData[
   EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityArea", fooArea}]], 
  4],
 {fooArea, fooAreaList},
 Initialization :> {
   fooAreaList = Sort@DeleteDuplicates@*Flatten@  
      WolframLanguageData[WolframLanguageData[], "FunctionalityAreas"];}
]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

---

Explicit list of `"FunctionalityAreas"` in 10.4 as OP is having firewall issues connecting to Wolfram Cloud.

```
{"AlgebraicFunctions", "AlignmentFunctions", "AngleFunctions", \
"AnnotationFunctions", "ArrayFunctions", "ArrowOperatorFunctions", \
"AskFunctions", "AssociationFunctions", "AstronomyFunctions", \
"AsynchronousTaskFunctions", "AutocompleteFunctions", \
"BasicFunctions", "BinaryDataFunctions", "BitFunctions", \
"BooleanFunctions", "BoxFunctions", "BoxOptions", "ButtonFunctions", \
"CalculusFunctions", "CDFFunctions", "CellFunctions", \
"ChartFunctions", "CloudFunctions", "ClusteringFunctions", \
"CodeActionFunctions", "CodeEvaluationFunctions", \
"CodeFlowFunctions", "CodeInterruptionFunctions", "ColorFunctions", \
"ComparisonOperatorFunctions", "CompileFunctions", \
"ComplexFunctions", "ContentObjectFunctions", \
"ContinuedFractionFunctions", "ContinuousFourierFunctions", \
"ControllerFunctions", "ControlObjectFunctions", \
"ControlObjectOptions", "ControlSystemFunctions", \
"CryptographyFunctions", "DatabinFunctions", "DatasetFunctions", \
"DateFunctions", "DebugFunctions", "DeviceFunctions", \
"DialogFunctions", "DirectoryFunctions", "DiscreteCalculusFunctions", \
"DiscreteFourierFunctions", "DomainFunctions", "DynamicFunctions", \
"EntityFunctions", "EnvironmentFunctions", "ExpressionSizeFunctions", \
"ExpressionTestingFunctions", "ExternalProcessFunctions", \
"ExtractionFunctions", "FileSystemFunctions", "FinanceFunctions", \
"FittingFunctions", "FontFunctions", "FormattingFunctions", \
"FormFunctions", "FractalFunctions", "FrontEndExecutionFunctions", \
"FrontEndFunctions", "FrontEndOptions", "FunctionFunctions", \
"Functions", "GaugeFunctions", "GeodesyFunctions", \
"GeoGraphicsFunctions", "GeoGraphicsPrimitiveFunctions", \
"GeometricTransformFunctions", "GlobalOptions", "GrammarFunctions", \
"GraphBooleanPropertyFunctions", "GraphDistributionFunctions", \
"GraphicsFunctions", "GraphicsPrimitiveFunctions", \
"GraphTheoryFunctions", "GroupTheoryFunctions", "HistogramFunctions", \
"HyperlinkFunctions", "ImageFilterFunctions", "ImageFunctions", \
"InfinityFunctions", "IntegerFunctions", "InterpolationFunctions", \
"InterpreterFunctions", "IntervalFunctions", "LegendFunctions", \
"LibraryLinkFunctions", "LinearAlgebraFunctions", "LinkFunctions", \
"ListFunctions", "LocalObjectFunctions", "LogicFunctions", \
"MachineFunctions", "MachineLearningFunctions", "MathFunctions", \
"MathFunctionWindows", "MathOperationFunctions", "MatrixFunctions", \
"MenuFunctions", "MessagesAndPrintingFunctions", "MinMaxFunctions", \
"ModuleFunctions", "NamedGraphFunctions", "NamedGroupFunctions", \
"NotebookFunctions", "NumberFieldFunctions", "NumberFunctions", \
"NumberTheoryFunctions", "NumericConstantFunctions", \
"NumericFunctions", "NumericsPrecisionFunctions", \
"OperatorFunctions", "OptionFunctions", "PackageFunctions", \
"PacketFunctions", "PacletFunctions", "PageFunctions", \
"PaletteFunctions", "ParallelFunctions", "PatternFunctions", \
"PermutationFunctions", "PlottingFunctions", "PolynomialFunctions", \
"QuantityFunctions", "QuantityVariableFunctions", \
"RationalFunctions", "RawExpressionFunctions", "RealFunctions", \
"RecurrenceFunctions", "RegionFunctions", "RestructuringFunctions", \
"RootFunctions", "RuleFunctions", "ScheduledTaskFunctions", \
"SeriesFunctions", "ServiceFunctions", "SetFunctions", \
"SignalProcessingFunctions", "SliderFunctions", "SolvingFunctions", \
"SoundFunctions", "SpecialSymbols", \
"StatisticalDistributionFunctions", "StatisticalProcessFunctions", \
"StatisticalTestFunctions", "StatisticsFunctions", "StreamFunctions", \
"StringFunctions", "StructuralFunctions", "StyleFunctions", \
"SymbolAssignmentFunctions", "SymbolContextFunctions", \
"SymbolFunctions", "SymbolInformationFunctions", \
"SymbolValueFunctions", "TemplateFunctions", "TensorFunctions", \
"TestFunctions", "TextStringFunctions", "TimeMemoryFunctions", \
"TimeSeriesFunctions", "TravelFunctions", "VectorCalculusFunctions", \
"VectorTeeOperatorFunctions", "ViewerFunctions", "WaveletFunctions", \
"WolframAlphaFunctions"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But as the fire wall,`WolframLanguageData[WolframLanguageData[], "FunctionalityAreas"]` must be fail to run with my network.Any method to get the `funcAreas`?And if you show the `funcAreas` contain what something,I'll appreciate you very much.

Comment: I can cost small amount of time connected to the wolfram-data.If I run you code,it will be [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA7uA.png).So a good method to get the valus of a property can be is better for me.:)

Comment: Sorry I disturb you again.Can you help me list all of `MathFunctions`?And I think you can filter it by `WolframLanguageData[WolframLanguageData[], "FunctionalityAreas"]`

Comment: @yode It should be `WolframLanguageData[
 EntityClass[
  "WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityArea", "MathFunctions"}]]` but this is returning an empty list at the moment from version 10.3.  Not certain why that is the case as other functionality areas are returning list of functions.  Might be a bug.  Report it to WRI and see.

Comment: I think this is a bug too.And I'll report it.But `Select[WolframLanguageData[],MemberQ[WolframLanguageData[#,"FunctionalityAreas"],"MathFunctions"]&]` maybe get it.Just for the network firewall.So I need some help.:)

Comment: Try getting the `"FunctionalityAreas"` separate from `Select`. It might help. `wolfFuncAreas = 
  EntityValue[WolframLanguageData[], "FunctionalityAreas", 
   "EntityAssociation"]; Keys@Select[MemberQ["MathFunctions"]]@wolfFuncAreas`